# how can i append a class to jquery ui helper result

Tags: jquery

i am trying to append a class to jquery ui autocomplete message response. i tried a few things but no luck. here is the code from jquery ui that i am trying to append the style to

```
e.widget("ui.autocomplete",e.ui.autocomplete,{options:{messages:{noResults:"No search 
results.",results:function(e){return e+(e>1?" results are":" result is")+" available"}}}
```

here i am trying to add a class to No Search Results and another to x Results are available. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like:

```
e.widget("ui.autocomplete", e.ui.autocomplete, {
      options: {
        messages: {
          noResults: "No search 
results.",
          results: function(e) {
            return '<span class="my-class">' + e + (e > 1 ? " results are" : " result is") + " available</span>"
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion manishie, it kind of work, it output is as text though, i will just edit the helper class in jquery ui and that should do it. thanks once again.